# APIs for google datalab

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

I have a (maybe stupid) question: once I have created a program using google datalab's notebook can this program be called from an external script through APIs?
Actually it is the only thing that I could not understand of this product.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have installed datalab [locally](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-local), you could use `jupyter nbconvert` to execute your notebook from an external script. Here is a working example:

`jupyter nbconvert --to python --execute <notebook.ipynb>`

You will need to run this command inside the datalab docker container.

- Type `docker ps` to get the id of the datalab container
- Type `docker exec -t -i <docker container id> /bin/bash` to run a command inside the datalab docker container